# AngularJS change scope variable on ng-click passing the variable in a function

Tags: angularjs, variables, onclick, scope

Okay I have multiple scope variables.
I pass them into a toggle function like this.

```
<button ng-click="controller.toggle(controller.data.variable)">Change</button>
```

On click I want to change the variable like this

```
controller.toggle = function(data) {
    if(toggled) {
        data = 'test';
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

I have already searched for solutions but found nothing.

Comment: What's wrong with the above?

Comment: The variable "data" is updated but the scope variable itself (controller.data.variable) isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Does [this](http://codepen.io/o4ohel/pen/pjNjNG) help?

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div>
    <button ng-click="toggle('variable1')">Change Variable 1</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button ng-click="toggle('variable2')">Change Variable 2</button>
  </div>

  <pre>variable1: {{variable1}}</pre>
  <pre>variable2: {{variable2}}</pre>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.variable1 = 'on';
  $scope.variable2 = 'off';

  $scope.toggle = function(propName) {
    var val = $scope[propName];
    $scope[propName] = val === 'on' ? 'off' : 'on';
  };
});
```

UPDATED [example](http://codepen.io/o4ohel/pen/NGbGyE) (please don't hate me for using eval)

html:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>
    <button ng-click="toggle('settings.section.value1')">Change Variable 1</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button ng-click="toggle('settings.section.value2')">Change Variable 2</button>
  </div>

  <pre>variable1: {{settings.section.value1}}</pre>
  <pre>variable2: {{settings.section.value2}}</pre>
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    section: {
      value1: 'on',
      value2: 'off'
    }
  };

  $scope.toggle = function(prop) {
    var val = eval("$scope." + prop);
    if(val === 'on') {
      eval("$scope."+ prop +"= 'off'");
    } else {
      eval("$scope."+ prop +"= 'on'");
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: I also tried this, but the problem is that the variable is multidimensional. Something like settings.section.value, so accessing it like this doesn't work either (at least how I tried it)

Comment: @Marco I've updated the answer, but it's not pretty :)